# How can I Create a customized dashboard (according to my business needs) in Salesforce?

Tags: dashboard

I created two objects (**Volunteer, Project**) with `one-to-many` relationship. Now I want to create a **dashboard** where the user can see the percentage of project completed (Project has percentage-completed field in its database table). How can I do this thing? Should I use **dashboard** or create custom **layout**?

Comment: One Volunteer can have many projects? or one Project has many Volunteers? or both?  This kind of question is best asked on Salesforce Success if you don't get any answers here. SFSE etiquette is to show some effort and then folks will wade-in to help

Comment: One Volunteer has many projects. I'm not here to ask about relationship thing. I want to know the view thing. How can I fulfill my requirement, that is,  create a dashboard where the user can see the percentage of project completed

Answer (score 2):

In your case, Parent Object is **Project** and Child Object is **Volunteer**. If it is Correct, Follow the below steps

1) Create a **Report Type** with **Valid Name** and Choose **Report Type Category** as **Other Reports**.

2) After Clicking NEXT, you will be asked for choosing the Objects. Now First Choose, **Project** (which will become a Primary Object). After that choose the **Volunteer** (as Child Object) within the Picklist.

3) And then Create a Report by choosing the Created Report type at the Starting Selection. Now you can be able to use the Fields of both Objects

4) Drag and drop both the Name Fields of Project and Volunteer Objects and also the Percentage Field to Preview as a Columns.

5) Now Click on the Dropdown of the Project column and Choose **"Group by this Field"** within it.

6) If you want the Total Percentage of Volunteers, Click on Dropdown of the Percentage Field and Choose **"Summarize this Field"**.

7) Lastly, Click on Save and Run the Report

**//Update**

8) For Dashboard, Just Click on "New Dashboard" button and create a Dashboard linking above Report and Save that Dashboard with appropriate name

Hope this helps.....